# Continously display textboxes per row in a table if a button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery

Hi pls help me with this. I created text boxes with names qty, serialno and description respectively in a row of a table. right after the text box description, i put a plus button that will display another text boxes below which is the same with the first ones. My problem is how can I continuously add up to 10 maximum rows of text boxes. Any help will do thanks!

Here is my markup:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td width="6"></td>

    <td align="left" width="3">Quantity<font color="#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input id=
    "qty" name="qty" type="text"></td>

    <td width="8">S/N<font color="#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input id="serialno" name=
    "serialno" type="text"></td>

    <td width="140">Desription<font color="#990000">*</font></td>

    <td><input id="desc" name="desc" required="required" type="text"></td>

    <td align="left" width="8"><button id="addreturn">+</button></td>
</tr>

<tr id="returnplus">
    <td id="returnplus" width="6"></td>

    <td align="left" id="returnplus" width="3">Quantity<font color=
    "#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input id="qty2" name="qty2" type="text"></td>

    <td id="returnplus" width="8">S/N<font color="#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input id=
    "serialno2" name="serialno2" type="text"></td>

    <td id="returnplus" width="140">Desription<font color="#990000">*</font></td>

    <td id="returnplus"><input id="desc2" name="desc2" type="text"></td>
</tr>
```

Here's the javascript:

```
< script > 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#returnplus").hide();
    $("#addreturn").click(function() {
        $("#returnplus").show("slow");
    });
}); 
< /script>
```

Comment: __IDs__ must be __unique__ in HTML. Use class selector instead.

Comment: what is this `</tr id="returnplus">` ?

Comment: @jeekonline the code i posted only do the displaying up to 2 rows. my problem is how can i add up to 10 rows. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will generate `textbox` elemets mentioned in `htmlvalue` upon clicking `+` button.

```
   var count = 1 ;
   $("#addreturn").click( function (e) {
   var htmlvalue = ' var htmlvalue = '<br>
  <br> ';
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" width="3">
      Quantity*&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="qty" name="qty" type="text">
    </td>
    <td width="8">
      S/N*&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="serialno" name="serialno" type="text">
    </td>
    <td width="140">
      Desription*
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="desc" name="desc" required="required" type="text">
    </td>
    <td align="left" width="8"></td>
  </tr>
</table>';

   if(count <= 10)
          $("body").append(htmlvalue);  
       else
          e.preventDefault();
    count = count + 1;

});
});
```

Also, Check **[DEMO FROM HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/w389t/2/)**

Comment: the code i posted only do the displaying up to 2 rows. my problem is how can i add up to 10 rows. thanks

Comment: @ninja3 : Okey, I got it. Kindly check my post update. Let me kn ow for any changes ... :-)

Comment: thanks man! i got it. now, my problem is how will i get the data inputted in each textboxes if they have the same text box names? thanks!!!!!

Comment: You can loop through input fields like this   `$("table input[type=text]").each( function() { });` and get the value as `this.value`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Change yout html and JS. replace id by class

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td width="6"></td>
    <td width="3" align="left">Quantity<font color="#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" />
    <td width="8">S/N<font color="#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input type="text" name="serialno" id="serialno"  />
    <td width="140" >Desription<font  color="#990000">*</font></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="desc" id="desc" required= "required"/></td>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font color="#990000"></font>
    </td>
    <td width="8" align="left"><button id="addreturn">+</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="returnplus">
    <td width="6"></td>
    <td width="3" align="left">Quantity<font color="#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input type="text" name="qty2" id="qty2"/>
    <td width="8">S/N<font color="#990000">*&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input type="text" name="serialno2" id="serialno2" />
    <td width="140">Desription<font  color="#990000">*</font></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="desc2" id="desc2" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.returnplus').hide();
        $('#addreturn').click(function(){
           $('.returnplus').show();
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: the code i posted only did displaying up to 2 rows. my problem is how can i add up to 10 rows. thanks

Comment: do u want to add rows dynamically?